# Preg_match (yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss) - only this format

Tags: php, regex, date

```
function Check_Date_Time($date_time)
{
 if (preg_match("/(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2}) (\d{2}):(\d{2}):(\d{2})/", $date_time))
   {
     return true;
   }
     else 
     {
     return false;
     }
}   

if(Check_Date_Time($date)){
    //echo 'correct';
}else{
    die();
}
```

If I set the date as such

```
["DueDate3"]=> string(24) "2014-10-17 21:10:1751111"
```

the validator let its trough, I got no ideas why :/ If it is a properly used date format it returns true. I don't really can use other formats - only this is acceptable

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Add start `^` and end `$` anchors to your regex.

```
if (preg_match("/^(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2}) (\d{2}):(\d{2}):(\d{2})$/", $date_time))
```

Answer (score 3):

```
 ^  Start of string or line  
\A  Start of string  
 $  End of string or line  
\Z  End of string
```

Try to put some of these anchor characters in the code:

```
preg_match("/^(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2}) (\d{2}):(\d{2}):(\d{2})$/", $date_time)
```

You can find more basic characters for regexp [here](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=regexp).

Answer (score 1):

Add anchors to your regex:

```
 if (preg_match("/^(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2}) (\d{2}):(\d{2}):(\d{2})$/", $date_time))
```

Answer (score 0):

try this regex expression

```
$date_time = "2019-02-21 11:25:34";
if (preg_match("/^[0-9]{4}-(0[1-9]|1[0-2])-(0[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-1]) (0[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3]):([0-5][0-9]):([0-5][0-9])$/", $date_time)
```

this might help you out. Thanks

Comment: Please explain your answer, regex might not be easy to understand for everyone

Comment: This returns true for a number of invalid dates like 2016-02-30 and 2016-09-31.
You can use a preg_match with a checkdate php function
[link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.checkdate.php)